# Get position of clicked element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title suggests, we are trying to get the position of the button that was pressed in angular. 
Is this possible?

The reason being is that we currently have an ng-grid. On each row in column 1 there is a button. On click of the button we would like to position a menu underneath it.

We have the menu, etc all working, however, we are struggling to get the physical position of the button, which in turn will allow us to position the menu directly underneath.

Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(e) {
    var pos = e.target.getClientRects()[0];
    var left = pos.left;
    var top = pos.top;
}
```

Comment: we need it to be in angular. Also, we couldnt use 'ID' as the button is repeated multiple times within an ng-grid.